# Parse left associative operators using a greedy parser

Tags: parsing, grammar, associativity

This seems to be a pretty fundamental flaw of greedy parsers that you cannot parse left associative operators because infinite recursion will always occur. Is there a way to prevent this from happening or is this just reality?

Comment: You parse the same language with a different grammar and then fix the parse tree. In practice, you can use techniques [like the one described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71771279/1566221). Of course, you can always use a different parsing algorithm.

Comment: Ah too bad my parser does not include that feature. Thanks for answering.